# Is there a way to read environment variables from CodeCommit inside Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a serverless.yml file where I need to expose some variables for Lambda.
These are environment variables declared within CodeCommit on AWS.

```
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: handler.test
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${environment.DB_HOST}
```

I'm not sure how exactly to get the DB_HOST from the set environment variables.
It's stored as Plaintext.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Try `${env:DB_HOST}`.

Relevant documentation: [Referencing Environment Variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/).